# Converting sql to cake ORM

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables: cars and users

A car can have an owner -> Foreign key to table users
 and the driver (can be different from owner) -> Also foreign key to users

Let's say I have a specific reason to use this query:

```
$cars= json_encode($this->Cars->get($carsid[0]['id'], [
                        'contain' => ['Color','Model'] 
                        ]),JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

if I add 'Users' in contain I'll get the owner user and not the driver

How can I get the driver?

I've tried innerJoin and matching but it does seem to work with the get method

Comment: Did you set Cars belongs to Drivers in your CarsTable? If so you simply do `'contain' => ['Driver', 'Model' ...]`

Comment: Driver is a column in table Cars and not a table @arilia

Comment: I know it is not a table. Nevertheless  you can associate your CarsTable to UsersTable and tell cake that it should refer it as Drivers. See my answe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the manual says

> As you can see, by specifying the className key, it is possible to use
>   the same table as different associations for the same table. You can
>   even create self-associated tables to create parent-child
>   relationships:

so you can do

```
class CarssTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'className' => 'Users',
        ]);


        $this->belongsTo('Drivers', [
            'className' => 'Users',
        ]);
    }
}
```

so you can do

```
'contain' => ['Drivers', 'Models' ...]
```